# Convert MSSQL Query to Lambda Expressions or LINQ. Grouping Sum and Sorting

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, sum

I have a SQL Query to extract sorted data by sum of a column value. I have a table named `CustomerPoint` and It has 2 columns named `CusTomerID` and `Point` , I want to extract the person with the highest `SUM` of points. Here is my SQL Query and it runs properly. But I need to execute it in EF6.3 with `LambdaExpressions` or `Linq` queries.

```
SELECT SUM(Point) AS POINTS, CustomerID FROM CustomerPoint AS POINTS GROUP BY CustomerID ORDER BY POINTS
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
from p in context.Points
group p by p.CustomerID into gr
select new { CustomerID = gr.Key, POINTS = gr.Sum(c=>c.Point) } into re
orderby re.POINTS
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
from cp in db.CustomerPoints
Group cp by cp.CusTomerID into cpg
select new { CusTomerID = cpg.Key, Points = cpg.Sum(c => c.Point)}
orderby cpg.Points
```

Answer (score 1):

And lambda form for diversity:

```
var query = youContext.CustomerPoints
            .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerID)
            .Select(x => new { Points = x.Sum(y => y.Point),
                               CustomerID = x.Key })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Points);
```